# how to connect gridview to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, database-connection

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvStudentDetails" runat="server" 
            ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CellPadding="4"  
            GridLines="None" OnRowDeleting="grvStudentDetails_RowDeleting">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="From">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="drpQualification" runat="server" >
                <asp:ListItem Value="G">kolkata</asp:ListItem>

                <asp:ListItem Value="P">Mumbai</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="To">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:DropDownList ID="drQualification" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="G">Bangalore</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="P">Delhi</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Travel Date">
        <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
        <ItemTemplate>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
        <ItemTemplate>

        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" 
                    Text="Add New City" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

> i have the following gridview in my asp page, now i want to connect all the contents means from,to, date etc..of this gridview to my database on click of save button, how i will do this, what all i have to do in my .cs file.PLZZZ HELP

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string insrt = "insert into book_mas_det(book_date,book_from,book_to,travel_date,return_date,adult_pax,child_pax,travel_class,contact_name,pnr_no,tot_amt,adv_amount,travler_rmks,agent_rmks) values (@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f,@g,@h,@i,@j,@k,@l,@m,@n)";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(insrt, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", txtbookingdate.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", ddlfrom.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", ddlto.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", txtdeprtr.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", txtreturn.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", txtadult.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g", txtchild.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@h", ddlclass.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i", txtcontpername.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@j", txtcontmobile.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@k", txtamnttocharge.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l", txtadvamnt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m", txtcmnttrav.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", txtcmntagnt.Text);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    string display = "Booking Details is added successfully";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);
```

> i have added my .cs code for the view1 connectivity,now how to do the connectivity for view2 and view3

Comment: grid.DataSource = datasource ;
grid.Bind()

Comment: @DoobyInc: Under which funtcion i have to use this?

Comment: In your code behind , handle the OnBeforePageLoad event, I am not sure the event name , But you can search on google, There are many examples avaialbe out there

Answer (score 0):

this might help u..!! this is my code..!!you could replace your template field texbox ids..!! i think you know how to save string values to table in database..!! i think this code is sufficient for you.!! i would like to know from you..!!

```
 try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gvInvTransaction.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            TextBox txtproduct = (TextBox)gvInvTransaction.Rows[i].FindControl("txtProduct");
            TextBox txtBarcode = (TextBox)gvInvTransaction.Rows[i].FindControl("txtBarCode");
            TextBox txtPrdctBatchID = (TextBox)gvInvTransaction.Rows[i].FindControl("txtPrdctBatchID");
            TextBox txtPrdctID = (TextBox)gvInvTransaction.Rows[i].FindControl("txtPrdctID");
            TextBox txtStdPurchasePrice = (TextBox)gvInvTransaction.Rows[i].FindControl("txtUnitPrice");
            TextBox txtStdSalesPrice = (TextBox)gvInvTransaction.Rows[i].FindControl("txtUnitPrice");





            string  ProductID = Convert.ToInt64(txtPrdctID.Text);
            string  StdPurchasePrice = Convert.ToDouble(txtStdPurchasePrice.Text);
            string  StdSalesPrice = Convert.ToDouble(txtStdPurchasePrice.Text);







        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Comment: actually i have one multiview in which 3 views are there..this gridview comes under 3rd view. so do i have to add new funtion for that and then add ur codes or something else..???

Comment: i think u need to save the details in gridview to database on button click ?? right??

Comment: actually i have 3 views in a multiview, for each view i have to do the database connectivity.This gridview part is in 3rd view,so how can i do that,i have to use 3 functions separately for all 3 views or something else?

Comment: i have connected view1 to the database, and its working but for others how i will do it

Comment: yes..!! you are having 3 different controls in 3 views..!! so u call 3 different functions to save() and bind the controls..!! i think if u post your asp.net code after trying will be more helpful to answer..!!
i am indeed so happy to help..!!

Comment: where is this button1 located ?? Is it outside all the views.??

Comment: so u must add the other 2 functions to save to database in this button1 click event itself..!!

Comment: thanks for the help..do i have to proceed the same way in which i have done in this function.?..how to start that new function can u give some idea by editing some steps in my code.?...it would be of great help..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("Insert into "Your table" "Your Values"");
cmd.executeNonquery();
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
DataAdapter da=new DataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
GridView1.Datasource=dt;
Gridview1.databind();
```

May be these ADO.Net will helpful to store Gridview values in database.
It should be done in button_click event, so that your values will store in database.

Comment: actually i have one multiview in which 3 views are there..this gridview comes under 3rd view. so do i have to add new funtion for that and then add ur codes or something else..???

Comment: What function you are going to add?,Could you brief some more.

Comment: actually i have 3 views in a multiview, for each view i have to do the database connectivity.This gridview part is in 3rd view,so how can i do that,i have to use 3 functions separately for all 3 views or something else?

Comment: i have connected view1 to the database, and its working but for others how i will do it.

Comment: Yeah, You have to connect database for each view. On third view you will have a submit button under your grid view right?. Give my above code to that button event.

Comment: For your further clarification see this link for Multiview  outlook design [http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/ms/aspdotnet/multiview.html ] . In this we can easily write functions for each view. I think you may get some Idea by this.Still If you struggle let me know.!

Comment: i have submit button outside the multiview.in third view i have just a grid view thats it.for the first view I have done done the naming conventions and I have done the database connectivity  and it's working. But for the second view i cannot give the same names like ddlfrom,ddlto,etc...so how to do the database connectivity for the second view...do I have to add another function or click event for second view connectivity or do I have to add some conditions in my given function or ..some other different ways to connect all the views to my database.

Comment: You may use onprerender event for views to join. U go through this link[ http://www.maddysoft.co.in/blog/multiple-page-forms-with-multiview-control-in-asp-net-2-0/ ] and kindly check out the "source file download line", in that you do download and have that code on your project and check it. I think it may rectify your issues.

Comment: Let me know, if my thoughts are worked for you.And one more thing If You want to store all the View members in database, the code which you mentioned is won't suit. You have to get all the view members to one page(ur page load), finally you do submit button event operation.

Comment: i will have one submit button event no.???...in which i can do the operations for all views..

Answer (score -1):

just create another string and Sql command object for the other 2 database inserts and add parameters,in parameters pass the string values taken from gridview,then call  cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery(); and cmd2.execute..!! the below is just a sample replace it with your each view values..!! hope it helps..!! :)

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string insrt = "insert into book_mas_det(book_date,book_from,book_to,travel_date,return_date,adult_pax,child_pax,travel_class,contact_name,pnr_no,tot_amt,adv_amount,travler_rmks,agent_rmks) values (@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f,@g,@h,@i,@j,@k,@l,@m,@n)";
    string insrt2 = "insert into book_mas_det(book_date,book_from,book_to,travel_date,return_date,adult_pax,child_pax,travel_class,contact_name,pnr_no,tot_amt,adv_amount,travler_rmks,agent_rmks) values (@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f,@g,@h,@i,@j,@k,@l,@m,@n)";
    string insrt3 = "insert into book_mas_det(book_date,book_from,book_to,travel_date,return_date,adult_pax,child_pax,travel_class,contact_name,pnr_no,tot_amt,adv_amount,travler_rmks,agent_rmks) values (@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f,@g,@h,@i,@j,@k,@l,@m,@n)";

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(insrt, conn);
    MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(insrt2, conn);
    MySqlCommand cmd3 = new MySqlCommand(insrt3, conn);

    //cmd parameters
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", txtbookingdate.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", ddlfrom.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", ddlto.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", txtdeprtr.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", txtreturn.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", txtadult.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g", txtchild.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@h", ddlclass.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i", txtcontpername.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@j", txtcontmobile.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@k", txtamnttocharge.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l", txtadvamnt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m", txtcmnttrav.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", txtcmntagnt.Text);

   //cmd2 parameters -replace this with your second view values 
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", txtbookingdate.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", ddlfrom.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", ddlto.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", txtdeprtr.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", txtreturn.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", txtadult.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g", txtchild.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@h", ddlclass.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i", txtcontpername.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@j", txtcontmobile.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@k", txtamnttocharge.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l", txtadvamnt.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m", txtcmnttrav.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", txtcmntagnt.Text);

   //cmd3 parameters- replace this with your third view values 
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", txtbookingdate.Text);
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", ddlfrom.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", ddlto.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", txtdeprtr.Text);
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", txtreturn.Text);
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", txtadult.Text);
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g", txtchild.Text);
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@h", ddlclass.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i", txtcontpername.Text);
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@j", txtcontmobile.Text);
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@k", txtamnttocharge.Text);
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l", txtadvamnt.Text);
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m", txtcmnttrav.Text);
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", txtcmntagnt.Text);




    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();
    string display = "Booking Details is added successfully";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);
```

Comment: hope it helps you,i would like to know,i have edited the code as you said..!! if you still need help..!! I  will be again ready to help..!!
Its a great feeling..!!

Comment: "Fatal error encountered during command execution"...its giving dis error...can u resolve this..